# three.js lock mesh at bottom right of screen

Tags: javascript, three.js

Currently I am developing a FPS with three.js. I have got a weapon which I want to lock at the bottom right of the screen, just like in any other FPS (so it looks like the user is holding a weapon).

I've come up with a basic proof of concept, which looks roughly like this:

```
fpsweapon.position.copy( user.position );
fpsweapon.position.y = user.position.y + 15;
```

So basically I am copying the position of my user model and then adding some offset, on every update. 
Is this the right approach? Has anyone ever done this before?

I have got the feeling this approach is a huge overkill.

Can anyone provide me with some thoughts or urls on how to do this elegantly?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not add fpsweapon to the scene, add it to user

```
user.add (fpsweapon);
```

Then set its position to (0, 15, 0).

This will be the weapon position relative to its container (user), and you won't need to change it anymore.

Comment: ah didn't even think of that.. elegant indeed!

Comment: The accepted answer did lead to a working prototype. However, there were too many downsides to deal with. I suddenly got the idea to use a gif which in turn lead me to using SPRITES! This is much more lightweight and easier to control.